# Xamarin Forms error diagnostic when laying out root page (Platform.LayoutRootPage)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When working on application written in Xamarin Forms, quite ofter I see the following exception which causes application to crash:

```
11-16 11:00:40.009 I/MonoDroid(16094): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x0000c] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:290 
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00003] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:199 
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0000e] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformRenderer.cs:73 
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094):   at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <e975227ac8644a30bb0866117325de0d>:0 
11-16 11:00:40.113 I/MonoDroid(16094):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:55caff06-7828-42f0-9580-cfb6673c4b5a (intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
```

Sometimes there is something wrong in XAML, sometimes, there is issue with view model binding (via attached property) but usually it takes me quite a lot of time to figure out where is the problem. Is there a way to get more information? Does Xamarin.Forms have a verbose logging which could be turned on to get more diagnostic information or something similar?

Also, in the MainActivity, I have the following code (using Serilog for logging):

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        ...
        RegisterExceptionHandlers();
        ...

    }
    private void RegisterExceptionHandlers()
    {
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += UnobservedException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
    }

    private void UnhandledException(object source, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Log.Error("Domain Exception from {source}: {exception}", source, args.ExceptionObject?.ToString() ?? "N/A");
    }
    private void UnobservedException(object source, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Log.Error("TaskSchedulerException: {source} {exception}", source, args);
        if (!args.Observed)
            args.SetObserved();
    }

    private void UnhandledExceptionRaiser(object source, RaiseThrowableEventArgs args)
    {
        Log.Error("Exception from {source}: {exception}", source, args.Exception?.ToString() ?? "N/A");
    }
```

But none of these events are triggered when the exception occurs. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: Got any solution @spatialguy??

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get more information?

You could use : [Diagnostic MSBuild Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output)

Here is the image :

[image]

> But none of these events are triggered when the exception occurs.

If the error is something wrong with your `XAML`, it was a **Compile Error**, it cant trigger your `ExceptionHandlers`.

Comment: This is not a build issue. It is a runtime problem. The application builds correctly but when it is launched (does not matter if on emulator or device) it crashes and the reference not set exception is reported.

Comment: @spatialguy, could you please share a Diagnostic MSBuild Output ? We need to see some error log to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @spatialguy, have you tried to use the debugger to find which line is crashing ?

Comment: Anyone found solution??